# Hardietrim/fiber cement for window trim on stucco

Tags: windows, trim, siding, stucco, cement-board

I have some leftover hardietrim from a side of a wall we accented with hardieplank. The rest of our house is stuccoed. We'd like to accent our windows that are on these stucco walls with trim. In lieu of architectural foam, could we use hardietrim?  Are there any major drawbacks in doing so? Could they be attached with construction adhesive and sealed with caulk?

Thanks

Comment: Id go with the foam as it is a tried and used for stucco. Hardy is heavy and I think you'd need to use some type of fastener to get it to remain in place.

Answer (score 1):

"Can it be..." The answer is probably Yes but consider that "hardie" (fiber cement board) products carry a warranty that requires strict adherence (pun intended) to their installation instructions. They do this to ensure that the products last as long as possible. Circumventing the install requirements by using non-approved install methods like adhesive is unwise. You can look up the warranty-approved install methods, I am not 100% certain adhesive is not allowed but all of the Hardie I've had installed used nails at specific intervals.

That said, in DIY there's a certain measure of taking risks. As long as your construction adhesive provides a positive connection, is sealed by caulk and then painted, you probably won't run into issues. Maybe try it on an inconspicuous rear window and make sure you're happy with the results before proceeding with the others.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the weight, as hardy is heavy, and getting it to stay on with just some adhesive then some warranty that wouldn't be applicable.